# Query for transient fields via ContentProvider in Android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

For an Android app, I have implemented a ContentProvider for accessing a SQLite database. Now I want to add additional values for a fixed set of non-existing fields to the query. For the consumer, there is no difference between table field an transient field. Because the fields have to be part of the contract.
How can I enhance the query inside the ContentProvider so that the Cursor includes these fields.
As an example: The database table 'event' has a field 'timestamp' and the query should be enhanced with a transient field 'duration', calculated at runtime by the timestamps of two selected entries.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Within the query method, I select the data from the database with a local Cursor. Then the result set, enriched with the transient attributes, will be copied into a MatrixCursor. This MatrixCursor will be returned by the ContentProvider's query method.

```
public class BikeHistProvider extends ContentProvider {

// Contract 
public final class Contract {
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    /** Calculated at run time */
    public static final String KEY_MY_TRANSIENT_FIELD = "myTransientField";
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, 
                    String selection, String[] selectionArgs, 
                    String sortOrder) {

    // Create a Cursor with the field structure defined in
    // Contract
    MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{
        Contract.KEY_ID,
        Contract.KEY_NAME
        Contract.KEY_MY_TRANSIENT_FIELD
        });                 

    // Apply the query to the underlying database.
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null, null, orderBy);

    //Move result to MatrixCursor and add transient fields
    c.moveToFirst();
    do {
        //Create new entries
        Object[] values = {
        c.getInt(0), //The key for the database entry
        c.getString(Contract.KEY_NAME),
        calculateTransientField()};

        mc.addRow(values);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
    c.close();

    return mc;
    }
}
```